# Why does HLS choose TS container?

Tags: http-live-streaming, transport-stream

I read [HTTP Live Streaming Specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-19#section-3).

But I don't get Why HLS choose TS format as standard.
HLS is based on HTTP that is reliable communication. Thus, I think PS format is more appropriate than TS.

is There anyone who knows? technical history??

Comment: Momentum of the format, I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

It was a choice apple made. They have not explained why they chose it. So anyone who answers, is just guessing.

I believe the most likely reason is Because it’s common to have native support for ts parsing in many video decoder chips.